# Running different projects on the same port (local host)

Tags: node.js, localhost

So I have been experimenting with web development lately, and created a few small projects as my playground.

There's this project I call 'CueClick' which I started out with first. It basically consists of the usual files: index.html, styles.css, and some javascript files. I ran it on localhost:8000 (just by clicking index.html), and it worked like a charm, nothing wrong there.

Later on, I went to play with a new project, 'socket'. Again, it consists of index.html, styles.css, some javascript files, and a server.js file. This time, I ran the project using `node server.js`, and since inside `server.js` I have this segment:

```
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000);
```

I opened localhost:8000 on my computer again, expecting to see the new web page there. Strangely, localhost:8000 still showed as the old project (i.e. CueClick).

What is happening here? How do I resolve this issue? I tried searching for an answer to this question, but I'm afraid it's so basic that a google search like "running different projects on localhost 8000" did not give me much help. Please explain in layman terms (if possible), or provide a link to a comprehensible explanation :( Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 8000 is already in use and can therefore not be bound to another process (if you are using TCP).

Since your server.js has this line it will favor an environmental variable `PORT` and default to `8000`:

```
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000);
```

You can set up an environmental variable when you start 'socket':

```
PORT=8001 node server.js
```

This will run 'socket' on localhost:8001.

Comment: So a port can only ever be bound to a single process? If I wasn't clear enough in my question, I wasn't running the two projects concurrently, but rather sequentially :/ And while I was considering switching ports (as you suggested) wouldn't this waste many ports if I have many projects later on?

Comment: Ports are represented as a 16bit integer, so you get over 65,000.  If you are running more processes than that, yes, you should start to worry :)

Comment: Why did localhost:8000 show your other process if it wasn't running?  Maybe a browser cache issue?

Comment: oh interestingly, when I just typed in localhost:8000 in my browser, I can still see the old 'CueClick' project even though my terminal is clean...but not say localhost:3000, which I played with before as well...reading up on browser cache issues now, thanks for the suggestion